# Mandrill webhooks: How to get notifications about successful delivery?

Tags: mandrill

I have webhooks configured for "send", "hard_bounce" and "soft_bounce".

- At 15:12 I got an event from mandrill that email message was hard
  bounced.
- At 15:14 I got an event from mandrill that the very same
  email message was sent.

messages.info API call says that the state of this message is "bounced".

1. Why mandrill behaves like that? Maybe it's a bug?
2. If it's not a bug then how to get notifications about successful delivery?
3. How to contact mandrill and file a bug report? I didn't find any place I could do that.

**Update (20.04.2015)**
Can you say that mail got delivered, if it contains positive smtp_events and state is sent?

Comment: Occasionally, Mandrill will send their events out of order. You'll have to compensate.

Comment: @DylanMoore So, usually it sends "send" event first and then "hard_bounce"? Hm, I will test. Thank you!

Comment: I think my problem is that I misunderstood that "sent" isn't the same as "delivered".

Comment: Added a new question to the main message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually cannot get a webhook notification for when the email is delivered through Mandrill.

The only way of checking if an email has been delivered is to poll Mandrill (with the [message/info.json API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=info)). To see if the message is delivered you have to check the `smtp_events` and look for an event with `diag` starting with 250.